Android 13 can't remount super partition after got root permission
First of all , I got root permission, disable-verity ,and disable-verification in vendor.
OS: A13.
KRNL: 4.14.276.
ROOT: got.
Question:
How should i do for remount system partition for read and write allowed without flash whole system to user_debug edition aosp rom package?
coral:/data/local/tmp # ./remount
failed to remount partition dev:/dev/block/dm-1 mnt:/: Read-only file system
Consider providing all the dependencies to enable overlayfs
failed to remount partition dev:/dev/block/dm-4 mnt:/system_ext: Read-only file system
Consider providing all the dependencies to enable overlayfs
failed to remount partition dev:/dev/block/dm-2 mnt:/vendor: Read-only file system
Consider providing all the dependencies to enable overlayfs
failed to remount partition dev:/dev/block/dm-3 mnt:/product: Read-only file system
Consider providing all the dependencies to enable overlayfs


I think that you first of all need to be on a userdebug build,
then try to:

adb root
adb disable-verity
adb reboot
Wait for device to reboot
adb root
adb shell
Make sure verity is disabled - avbctl get-verity
mount -o rw,remount /system


It isn't a userbug build , it's a factory product build , userdebug build isn't right for me.

@jdir.s that's probably the problem, you cannot do this on production build..
